# TypeScript - How to annotate types in this code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a method in my library that can register a bunch of user-provided event listeners. Here is a simplified example:

```js
function registerEventListeners(events: Record<string, EventListenerOrEventListenerObject>): void {
  for (const [name, handler] of Object.entries(events)) {
    window.addEventListener(name, handler)
  }
}

const customEvents = {
  keydown: (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

registerEventListeners(customEvents)
```

TypeScript is giving me this error at the call site of `registerEventListeners`...

```
~      1. Argument of type '{ keydown: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, EventListenerOrEventListenerObject>'.
~           Property 'keydown' is incompatible with index signature.
~             Type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
~               Type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
~                 Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
~                   Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.
```

The `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject` generic seems to be unable to guarantee that my keydown event handler will receive the correct event type. So what is the correct way to type this code?

Comment: This is because an EventListener expects the parameter `Event`, while your function expects a `KeyboardEvent`. Because you have typed the `events` parameter as a record of event listeners that take any events, you have no safety that another kind of Event will be passed to your keydown handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment describes, you are doing this:

```
(event: Event) => void;         // defined type
        |                       // lying to the given type
        V                       // by passing any event to it
(event: KeyboardEvent) => void; // given type
```

You can however use this compromise, sacrificing a line for `//@ts-ignore`, but getting the expected behavior for the end-user. Essentially you are now expecting a map of event names to the correct event type, instead of any string to the generic Event type.

```
function registerEventListeners(events: Partial<{
    [K in keyof WindowEventMap]: (event: WindowEventMap[K]) => void;
}>): void {
  for (const [name, handler] of Object.entries(events)) {
    //@ts-ignore
    window.addEventListener(name, handler);
  }
}

const customEvents = {
  keydown: (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      // ...
    }
  }
}

registerEventListeners(customEvents)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRlPEm)